# CXF- FileNotFoundException with Maven and Tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, cxf, filenotfoundexception

I try to get a web-app running within Tomcat 7. I'm using Maven and with the jetty-Plugin everything works fine. When building the war and deploying it to Tomcat7, I get a FileNotFoundException for the Keystore-File.

Where do I have to put the File and what path do I have to use in cxfClient.xml?

pom.xml Snippet:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <xsd>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd/template1.xsd</xsd>
                                <packagename>some.packagename</packagename>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <!-- <wsdl>URLTOWSDL</wsdl> -->
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/test/resources/somewsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

cxfClient.xml:

```
      <sec:keyManagers>
      <sec:keyStore file="truststore.jks" password="test1234" type="JKS"/>
  </sec:keyManagers>
  <sec:trustManagers>
      <sec:keyStore file="truststore.jks" password="test1234" type="JKS"/>
  </sec:trustManagers>
```

Line from the Logfile:

```
Error creating bean with name 'servicename.http-conduit': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig] while setting bean property 'tlsClientParameters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public static java.lang.Object org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParametersConfig.createTLSClientParameters(java.lang.String)] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\resources\truststore.jks (Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden)
```

I tried src/main/resources, src/main/webapp with different paths in the cxfClient, but always get the FileNotFoundException.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need keystore file by default, what keystore file is this? A stacktrace can't hurt either.

Comment: I see you updated the question :) Define an absolute path to the jks file, otherwise it has to be in the root of the classpath (`WEB-INF/classes`, that is the `src/main/resources`). cxf-client.xml is usually in the `META-INF`, so it might have to be in that folder, if it is a relative to the xml.

Comment: Alread tried that :(
I've put cxfClient.xml and the truststore.jks into src/main/resources. I see them in WEB-INF/classes in the tomcat-Folder. I set "file="src/main/resources/truststore.jks". But still get the Exception...

Comment: Now that is a problem :) If you put them there, then they will be copied to the root of the classpath, which means the following setting should work `file="truststore.jks"`

Comment: That was my setting before (you see it in the code above).
I deploy with `mvn clean tomcat7:deploy`, I see the file in `WEB-INF/classes`, i get the Exception. When I use `mvn jetty:run`, everything works as expected..

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was a separate thing. Try to move the keystore to a separate folder on the appserver and use `file:///<drive>:/folder/file` as `file`. Otherwise tomcat's root path (not the classpath) is the `bin` folder, so you could try copying the jks there (just for testing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Keystores (as identified by the sec:keyStore element above) can be
>   identified via any one of three ways: via a file, resource, or url
>   attribute. File locations are either an absolute path or relative to
>   the working directory, the resource attribute is relative to the
>   classpath, and URLs must be a valid URL such as "http://..."
>   "file:///...", etc. Only one attribute of "url", "file", or "resource"
>   is allowed.

Source: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html

Comment: `<sec:keyStore resource="truststore.jks" password="test1234" type="JKS"/>`

"resource" instead of "file" is the way to go